# File Locking in C++ For simultaneous Read and Write Lock

Tags: c++

How can i lock a file for read and write operation. That is If "ABC" file name is in Write lock, it also provide Read Lock on the same locked file. In normal case we want to wait till write operation completion.So if there any ways to acquire this kind of locking

Comment: can be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13402294/create-a-locked-file-with-boostinterprocessfile-lock

Answer (score 3):

Many programs simply use a *lock file* to signify that a certain file is currently in use for writing.

The lock file is later removed when done writing.

For example, when process #1 is about to start writing to file `example`, it creates file `example.lock`. Later when done writing, it simply removes `example.lock`.

When process #2 want to read from file `example` it first checks if file `example.lock` exists. If it does then the file is locked for write operations and process #2 will have to wait.

Answer (score 0):

[shared_mutex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.mutex_types.shared_mutex) from Boost implements read/write locking.

Comment: locking a file works between processes; shared_mutex doesn't